# Não consigo compreender o porque desse valor NaN na coluna "[letalidadeRegionalSaude]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

```
#letalidade por estado
letalidadeRegionalSaude = []
for i in range(len(regional_saude)):
    letalidadeRegionalSaude.append(regional_saude.obitosNovos[i] * 100 / regional_saude.casosNovos[i])
print(letalidadeRegionalSaude)

[0.9345794392523364,
 4.123711340206185,
 3.4618410700236035,
 1.7267267267267268,
 4.545454545454546
...]

type(letalidadeRegionalSaude[1])
numpy.float64

#Adicionando uma coluna ao DataFrame
regional_saude['letalidadeRegionalSaude'] = pd.Series(letalidadeRegionalSaude)

regional_saude.head()

nomeRegiaoSaude       casosNovos     obitosNovos    populacaoTCU2019_int    letalidadeRegionalSaude
            
10ª REGIAO                 428             4              22328916.0                  NaN
```

Comment: `letalidadeRegionalSaude` é uma série não um número, por isso o `NaN`.

Comment: Não entendi!!! Mas não é possível inserir um lista como uma coluna em um dataframe? Pois, a minha intenção é está: converte uma lista com o método "pd.Series()" e colocar esta série como uma coluna no dataframe.

Comment: Pois foi isso o que eu fiz com a coluna "populacaoTCU2019_int". Está coluna era do tipo "object", eu a converter para inteiro e inserir no dataframe.

Comment: Converta a serie para string que vai conseguir o resultado desejado.

Answer (score -1):

Teoricamente o que você fez está certo, uma outra solução seria fazer da seguinte forma:

```
for i in regional_saude.index:
    regional_saude['letalidadeRegionalSaude'] = letalidadeRegionalSaude[i]
```